# Collecting values from fixed number of data frame rows into list, without aggregating operations

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, numpy-ndarray

I have the following panda's data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2022-10-01 01:00:00', '2022-10-01 02:00:00',
                                '2022-10-01 03:00:00', '2022-10-01 04:00:00',
                                '2022-10-02 01:00:00', '2022-10-02 02:00:00',
                                '2022-10-02 03:00:00', '2022-10-02 04:00:00'],
                   'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'B': [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3]}
                  )
df5['timestamp'] = df5['timestamp'].astype('datetime64')
#df4.set_index('timestamp', inplace= True)
df5
```

That gives the following data frame:

```
| timestamp          | A| B |
|--------------------|--| --|
| 2022-10-01 01:00:00| 1| 10|
| 2022-10-01 02:00:00| 2| 9 |
| 2022-10-01 03:00:00| 3| 8 |
| 2022-10-01 04:00:00| 4| 7 |
| 2022-10-02 01:00:00| 5| 6 |
| 2022-10-02 02:00:00| 6| 5 |
| 2022-10-02 03:00:00| 7| 4 |
| 2022-10-02 04:00:00| 8| 3 |
```

The target result is X data frame: (X should be of shape (# of samples,# of variables, # of timepoints ) (4, 1, 4) / for this example)

```
|      | values     | target|
|:---- |:----------:| -----:|
| 0    | [1,2,3,4]  | A     |
| 1    | [10,9,8,7] | B     |
| 2    | [5,6,7,8]  | A     |
| 3    | [6,5,4,3]  | B     |
```

This example considers four rows for collecting the values, but that can be another number of rows, for instance, twenty. I was thinking of iterating row by row, but since I have many rows, that approach is too slow.

Here is a demo of iterating approach (I admit, it is very spaghetti, but it's just for the purpose of demo) and the target result:

```
import numpy as np

master_A_B = [] #list for the overall values
masterA, masterB = [], [] # list for the column A and B
A_mini, B_mini = [], [] # list for the values of one 'window' in col A and  B
master_y = []  #list for target values
n = 4 # the size
for idx, row in df5.iterrows():
    if (idx+1)%n == 0:
        if idx == 0:
            A_mini.append(row['A'])
            B_mini.append(row['B'])
        else:
            A_mini.append(row['A'])
            B_mini.append(row['B'])
            masterA.append(A_mini)
            master_y.append('A')
            masterB.append(B_mini)
            master_y.append('B')
            master_A_B.append(masterA)
            master_A_B.append(masterB)
            A_mini, B_mini, masterA, masterB= [], [], [], []  #reset lists

    else:
        A_mini.append(row['A'])
        B_mini.append(row['B'])
print(master_A_B)
print(master_y)
print("========")
master_A_B_np = np.array(master_A_B)
print(master_A_B_np.shape)
master_y_np = np.array(master_y)
master_y_np.shape
```

and it gives the result I would like to achieve without simple iteration:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4]], [[10, 9, 8, 7]], [[5, 6, 7, 8]], [[6, 5, 4, 3]]]
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
========
(4, 1, 4)
(4,)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the target?

Thank you

Comment: i am a little confused by your explanation that `(X should be of shape (# of samples,# of variables, # of timepoints ) (4, 1, 4) / for this example)` because the output dataframe doesn't match that shape, and what does the column `left` mean? it also appears that there is also some dependence on the day – maybe if you create a column that extracts the day from the `timestamp` column and perform a groupby on that, you can get the desired output

Comment: @DerekO, thank you. "left" column was the wrong name for the column with the values. I fixed it. I mentioned the shape since I use the data in the data frame for the time-series classification after I get the desired result. Regarding the datetime column, I do not have an equal distance between data points, so I have to group them as the desired output.